# Calculation of DST in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the below code to calculate for different countries manually but it is not reflecting DST kindly guide me to achive the same now st Gallen time is 1 hour back.

```
<span id="clock01"></span>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function calcTime00(city, offset) {
setTimeout("1");
    d5 = new Date();
    d = new Date();
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);  
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));//by smt
    var area=""+city+"&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"+nd.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d{2}\s/,'  ');
    $('#clock01').html(area); 
    setTimeout(function () { calcTime00('','+2');}, 1000);    
}
</script>
```

Comment: `setTimeout("1");` ??

Comment: setTimeout("1"); refresh the digital clock in every 1 sec

Comment: kindly guide me to dynamically adjust the time during day light changes